# ParseObject not updated after trying to update/sve it in android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am trying to retrieve a row in my table on parse.  I found the objectId, but when I try to update the row with new information, nothing happens.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

```
mSaveAndNextSteps.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ParseQuery<SingleFactInfo> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Fact_Info");
            query.getInBackground(mEventObjectId, new GetCallback<SingleFactInfo>() {
                public void done(ParseObject fact, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        // Now let's update it with some new data. In this case, only cheatMode and score
                        // will get sent to the Parse Cloud. playerName hasn't changed.
                        fact.add("factDescriptiontwo", mEventDescription.getText().toString());
                        event.put("factDescription", mEventDescription.getText().toString());
                        event.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void done(com.parse.ParseException e) {

                            }
                        });
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void done(SingleFactInfo parseObject, com.parse.ParseException e) {
                    Intent goToFactLists = new Intent(CreateEventSectionTwo.this, EventList.class);
                    startActivity(goToFactLists);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: This might sound silly, but you got 2 public void done methods. The second one has@Override, so it'll be the method called when getInBackground is done.

Comment: Yeah I  know, i thought it was weird too.  However, when I try to implement it without the second one, i get an error that wont go away unless I implement it.  If i try to save the object in the second 'done', it gives me a null pointer exception.

Comment: Well, since your first done doesn't have (at)Override, removing the second done, including the (at)Override will error that it's missing an overriden method of done (aka (at)Override public void done()). Now, you've tried saving it before in the second done and it gave a nullpointer exception. My best guess is there somewhere among your saving code, is still an error that is triggered. Perhaps 'mEventDescription' is null, which would trigger a nullpointerexception when calling .getText() on it. I won't know for sure unless you might have a handy errorlog/stacktrace of the nullpointer crash :)

Comment: My friend, you are a genius!  Firstly, you were correct, I had one too many 'done' methods (In my hurry to find a solution, I forgot I added one as a test).  Second, my my mEventDescription was null, I found this out by showing a toast.  Works now, thanks again for the help through the form of dialog, very much appreciated!  I'll post my solution below.  Thank you again!.

Comment: You're welcome, enjoy! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the working solution that worked for me.  Queried the object using objectId, then updated it in the 'done' section.

```
mSaveAndNextSteps.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ParseQuery<SingleFactInfo> query = new ParseQuery("Event_Info");
            query.getInBackground(mEventObjectId, new GetCallback<SingleFactInfo>() {
                public void done(ParseObject event, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        // Now let's update it with some new data. In this case, only cheatMode and score
                        // will get sent to the Parse Cloud. playerName hasn't changed.
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mYourEditText.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void done(SingleFactInfo parseObject, com.parse.ParseException e) {
                    parseObject.put("eventDescription", mYourEditText.getText().toString());
                    parseObject.saveInBackground();
                    Intent goToFactsList = new Intent(YourApplication.this, EventList.class);
                    startActivity(goToFactsList);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```